# Tap (not hold) Right Alt key to toggle to hangul (Korean)

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, korean

I have to hold down the right alt key to type in English when using ibus-hangul and the Korean (hangul) keyboard layout. However, on other operating systems I can just tap right alt to toggle input from hangul to English and back again, rather than having to hold it down. How can I fix this?

To clarify, the alternate character input hotkey in keyboard settings is set to Right Alt (without this I cannot change layout at all).